How to Copy session (logged in users of gmail ) of a chrome from one computer to the other computer?
I bought a new laptop and I have copied all the data from one pc to another including the App data.
I want to transfer my logged in session of gmail from my old laptop to new laptop, without entering password again. How to do that?
I have tried copying pasting the cookies via cookie editor but that didn't work.
I have several profiles which have been moved, when I moved appdata of google chrome but gmails I have logged in old laptop, they have not moved  to new laptop.
How to move sessions of logged in gmail to new pc?
